# Anylogic - sink according to DB

Tags: database, anylogic

I am using Anylogic to simulate processes in a clinic. I am using a data base for the source which works perfectly. So patients arriving according to the date and quantity in data base (e.g. on 1th April 20 patients arriving).

In addition I want that patients are leaving the clinic according to the data base. (1th April 10 patients are leaving) But actually I do not know how to implement..

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The implementation depends on the process that patients go through in your clinic. 
However, each patient, anyway, should know when he/she should leave the clinic. You can read the corresponding data from DB and assign it to a patient's parameter, say "endOfTreatment", in the "Source" block.
If clinic process is simple like staying while under treatment, you need to delay a patient for (dateToTime(agent.endOfTreatment) - time()).
In case it is not known in which block the patient will be at the end of treatment, you may use a **[dynamic event](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/statecharts/Dynamic%20Event.html)** to schedule removing the patient form the current block at dateToTime(agent.endOfTreatment) (there is a function currentBlock() in Agent API).